# Can a cat be naturally skinny? or is she just fussy?

Tags: cats

I have a beautiful female tabby (1/3 siamese too I think) and she's always been skinny, I've tried her on multiple different brands of cat food (both wet and dry) and she only likes Gocat kibble, Felix and Whiskers, every other brand she mainly left in the bowl (especially kibble) and despite all the different brands I've tried her with she's still skinny. I can feel her hips a bit **(is that normal?)** I've heard that introducing some raw meat can help but I'm not sure if I should try her on that. She's outside a lot and she gets fed 3 times a day. any help, advice or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A cat can certainly be naturally skinny. I know one who was the runt of her litter and has been extremely thin all her life, to the point where you can easily count every bone. She is now 17 years old, having outlived two other cats in that household, so it certainly doesn't seem to have held her back.